# How do I change a bool value once an animation has played?

Tags: unity

I've designed a Dodge behavior for my player. On input the behavior is executed setting "isDodging" bool to true. My Animation also plays when "isDodging" is true.

I need a proper way to set "isDodging" to false once the Behavior is complete. Currently "isDodging" becomes false once touching the ground is detected, but I think the best way to handle this would be once the animation is complete or the animation has been canceled into a different behavior. What steps would you recommend?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Dodge : AbstractBehavior
{
    public float speed;
    public bool isDodging;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var canDodge = inputState.GetButtonValue(InputButtons[0]);

        if (!isDodging && canDodge)
            OnDodge();

        else if (isDodging && collisionState.standing)
            isDodging = false;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDodge()
    {
        var velocityX = speed * (float) inputState.direction;

        isDodging = true;
        body2D.velocity = new Vector2(velocityX, body2D.velocity.y);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference a Animator component and you can create a bool in the animation tab. to set it you can use anim.SetBool()

```
Animator anim

void Start{
anim = GetComponent<Animator>()
}

if (!isDodging && canDodge)
        OnDodge();

  //removed where you set to false

protected virtual void OnDodge()
{
    var velocityX = speed * (float) inputState.direction;

    isDodging = true;

    anim.SetBool("isDodging", isDodging);
    body2D.velocity = new Vector2(velocityX, body2D.velocity.y);

}
```

Comment: This seems to be what my animator is doing already, I set the animation state based on if my bool is true or false. is there a way to switch bools based on if the animation has started and finished?

Comment: Double check your states in the animator tab. you can blend the animations or choose to just play the one. but the problem I bet is that you are touching ground and setting false. add another parameter in the anim tab to check against or isdodging should probably play from any state like a jump animation would. So it would play dodge then go right into the state it should be after its done playing

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try it out. For things like my jump Animation, it checks to see if my Y-Velocity is higher than 0 and resets on touching the ground. My dodge and other behaviors aren't as easy to define what sets it to false so I need to solve those problems with a different method.

Comment: It looks like you can set Animation events at the end of frames, any idea if this is a bad way to go?

Comment: I would keep a bool for a dodge but you could accomplish with a anim event

Comment: I made a separate method that just sets the bool to false then executed it at the end of my animation and it seems to work. I'm sure I'll have to cover other exceptions in code but maybe it's a start.

Comment: Good Job, Happy Coding!